# valueForKeyPath returning nil unexpectedly

Tags: objective-c, swift, key-value-coding

This is a fairly short question, but I'm a bit confused on how to fix it.

```
for item in filteredAndSortedDates {
     print(item.datesSectionHeader()) // Returns a value
     print(item.value(forKeyPath: "datesSectionHeader") as Any) // Returns nil
     // The "as Any" part up above is just to keep the compiler quiet. It doesn't have any meaning as this is just for testing purposes.
}
```

I'm a bit confused on why this is happening. How come valueForKeyPath is returning `nil` when the above is returning a value? I'm calling this on an `NSDictionary`.

This is the log I'm getting:

```
HAPPENING THIS WEEK
nil
HAPPENING THIS WEEK
nil
HAPPENING THIS WEEK
nil
HAPPENING WITHIN A YEAR
nil
```

Here's how I'm declaring `datesSectionHeader`:

```
extension NSDictionary {

     // FIXME
     func datesSectionHeader() -> String {
         // Doing some work in here.
     }
}
```

Comment: print your log in your question

Comment: Sure! Let me add it in right now.

Comment: print(item.value(forKeyPath: "datesSectionHeader") as NSString)

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya Changing it to `NSString` isn't making a difference. It's just crashing the app as I have to force downcast an optional (that's nil) with `as!`.

Comment: HAPPENING THIS WEEK its your key ? in item array right

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya Yes, that's what the function is returning. I'm actually performing some checks and methods on the `value` of the dictionary to get that string.

Comment: print(item.value(forKeyPath: "datesSectionHeader") as Any) you must have to pass that key in datesSectionHeader so you got value . for testing just put static string, HAPPENING THIS WEEK and print did you got any value or no t

Comment: Can you tell us about the structure of *item*? Are you sure you haven't misspelled *datesSectionHeader* (take into account the upper and lower cases too)?

Comment: Please show your definition of the type of `item`. You may be declaring `datesSectionHeader()` in an non-KVC-compliant manner.

Comment: @Rikh Yes, I literally copied and pasted to double check.

Comment: @OOPer I'll modify the question right now :)

Comment: Are you sure it's an NSDictionary and not a Swift dictionary? How does `.datesSectionHeader()` work if it's a dictionary?

Comment: @jtbandes Yes, I'm 100% sure. Otherwise, I wouldn't even be able to call `valueForKeyPath` as a compiler error would be thrown saying that there's no function like that for a Swift dictionary.

Comment: Are you sure the extension function is called?

Comment: @Rikh Hmm.. this is strange. It's being called on the first one, but not on the valueForKey one

Comment: @Rikh Also, I'm testing that this is the case by adding in a breakpoint in the method.

Comment: Yeah that is how you should test. I'm not sure if you can call functions with KVO, someone else can maybe confirm that. Or maybe your syntax is wrong!

Comment: @Rikh I have some similar cases in my app where I'm doing this; however, it's with `CNContact` and not `NSDictionary`.

Comment: This might be a bug, you should consider filing it at bugs.swift.org.

Comment: @jtbandes Yeah! I'm honestly very confused myself as to why it isn't working. I'll probably wait a little bit longer and see if there are more ideas. If not I'll file a bug report.

Comment: `NSDictionary` overrides `valueForKey:` (Swift: `value(forKey:)`) to return its content value for the key and does not check the getter method for the key. (`value(forKeyPath:)` internally calls `value(forKey:)`.) As far as I tested, this behaviour is also found in Objective-C, so it's not a bug of Swift. You need to find a way around. You may need to wrap the dictionary with a class which defines `datesSectionHeader` in a KVC compliant manner.

Comment: @OOPer Hmm.. I think I get it. Could you maybe write your comment as a solution and provide a basic example. I kinda need to see the code for it to click in my head.

Comment: As a wrinkle to what @OOPer said, if you prefix a key with "@", then it accesses the dictionary's properties rather than its contents. So, `item.value(forKeyPath: "@datesSectionHeader")` would work.

Comment: @KenThomases, confirmed! Thanks for a nice tip.

Comment: @KenThomases Yes! That works! Would you like to post that as an answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSDictionary` modifies the standard behavior of Key-Value Coding so that it accesses the dictionary's contents rather than its properties. It does this by overriding `value(forKey:)` (which is, in turn, used by `value(forKeyPath:)`).

As [documented](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdictionary/1410210-value), its override of `value(forKey:)` checks if the key is prefixed by "@". If it's not, it returns the result of `object(forKey:)`, accessing the dictionary contents. If it is prefixed with "@", it strips the "@" and returns the result from the superclass's implementation, which accesses the dictionary's properties.

So, in this particular case, you can access the results from your `datesSectionHeader()` getter method using the following:

```
item.value(forKeyPath: "@datesSectionHeader")
```